# Using regex to extract string after certain number of characters

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

How do I extract the string after certain number of characters?
Eg. 0    HOPOPT          IPv6 Hop-by-Hop Option              `Y        [RFC2460]`

I want to select the highlighted part which is every character after 57th character. I need to make a replace in Sublime editor and have to specifically select the highlighted portion, how can I do that?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
.{57}(.*)
```

Everything after the 57th character will be captured in group 1.

Alternatively, if your platform supports it, you can use a lookbehind:

```
(?<=.{57}).*
```

Using sublime, simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the find options, select the regex option (<kbd>.*</kbd>) and enter in one of the above regular expressions. Here's a screenshot (with slightly modified regular expression, since what you say you want to hightlight actually appears to begin at the 32<sup>nd</sup> character.)

[image]